# JSON PRC 2, passing array in parameter through http URL

Tags: php, json

I am struggling to pass an array through JSON PRC.

http://localhost/archway-core/public/api/api.php?

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"addUdfValue","params":{"formId":"1",**"fields":"sdf"**,"token":"1234"},"id":1}
```

I am want to pass, `{"fname":"kamran","age":"50"}` in the fields of params.

Did any one knows that to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figure out this issue,

http://localhost/archway-core/public/api/api.php?

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"addUdfValue","params":{"formId":"1","fields":{"fname":"kamran","age":"50"},"token":"1234"},"id":1}